# How to rotate element on every window scroll event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have element, which should transform: rotate on window scroll. When that element is visible.
So now I have function, which watches visible or not that element. But now how to transform it? I want to add 1deg to rotation, when scrolling.

Comment: could you show some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a simple **jQuery**.

Take a look here:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/hhtyj5eg/

I hope this can help you. :)